# Access rights in firebase database/firestore

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

I need to grant permissions to a user for my Firebase project. But this user should only have **access** to adding data on **Real-Time Firebase Database**. I think it should be done here:

[image]

User can only **add** and **delete** data in **firebaseDatabase** and nothing more here:

[image]

How do I set permissions for this user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently is no way to give product-level permissions to a collaborator on the Firebase console. Either they have access to the console, or they don't have access. You *can* give them read-only access, but that doesn't sound like what you need.

Comment: It is a pity that it is impossible. Thanks for answer.